# Do I need a new EIN since I am hiring employees for my LLC?

Tags: small-business, employer

I have an LLC that I set up but at the time it was created, the business did not have any employees (this is for consulting work I am doing).  So I now have an EIN for this LLC but during the IRS interview I specifically said there would not be any employees for this company.  Now I am planning on hiring my wife as an employee (so that my business qualifies for small group health insurance).  Do I need to get a new EIN for my LLC because I now am hiring employees?  Or how do I tell the IRS that the old EIN will now have employees?

Comment: p.s. While business administration is generally off-topic, there is a *personal* angle here which, IMHO, keeps this question (marginally) on-topic.  Refer also to http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/15/are-small-business-questions-on-topic

Answer (score 3):

I called the IRS ([click here for IRS contact info](http://www.irs.gov/help/article/0,,id=96730,00.html)) and they said I do not need to get a new EIN.  I could have just filed the appropriate employer federal tax return (940/941) and then the filing requirements would have been updated.  But while I was on the phone, they just updated the filing requirements for my LLC so I am all good now (I still need to file the correct form and make the correct payments, etc. but I can use this same EIN going forward).

Disclaimer: Don't trust me (or this answer) for tax advice (your situation may be different).  The IRS person on the phone was very helpful so I recommend calling them if you are in a similar situation.  FYI, I have found calling the IRS to always be very helpful.